# Input / Output error in read /dev/sda during installation

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive, error-handling

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04, but when starting I get this error message:

```
Input/Output error during read on /dev/sda
```

I can't make partitions. Also I tried working this out with other Linux distros, like Manjaro GNOME, which was the OS I previously had, which messed up completely so had to remove it from the disk. I need some help here as my hard disk seems to be fine. Right now I am uploading this query using *Try Ubuntu* before installation. I checked if my bootable flash drive has any problem, but it doesn't. My SATA configuration is also set to AHCI. I have formatted my hard drive, and it is recognized by the OS.

On viewing my hard disk using Disk Utility:

[image: On viewing my hard disk using Disk Utility]

[image: On viewing SMART Data & Self Test using Disk Utility]

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 2029981696 bytes, 3964808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 89.1 MiB, 93417472 bytes, 182456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54.7 MiB, 57294848 bytes, 111904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 44.9 MiB, 47063040 bytes, 91920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 160.2 MiB, 167931904 bytes, 327992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 4.2 MiB, 4403200 bytes, 8600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4ACBAC48-BCA6-43C2-B3E6-35A0B2243FD7

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.5 GiB, 15597568000 bytes, 30464000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x14f142f8

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30463999 30461952 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

On `tail -f /var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979044] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979050] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:00:00:08:10/00:00:20:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 4096 out
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979050]          res 40/00:08:00:64:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979053] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979055] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979060] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:08:00:64:70/04:00:74:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 524288 out
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979060]          res 40/00:08:00:64:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979062] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979065] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979070] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:e8:00:08:10/04:00:00:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq dma 524288 out
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979070]          res 40/00:08:00:64:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979072] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979075] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979080] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:f0:a0:61:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 4096 in
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979080]          res 40/00:08:00:64:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979082] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979084] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979088] ata1.00: cmd 61/08:f8:00:08:12/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 4096 out
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979088]          res 40/00:08:00:64:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979090] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979096] ata1: hard resetting link
```

[image]

```
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.190508] ata1.00: detaching (SCSI 0:0:0:0)
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.190714] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.190722] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost async page write
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.190785] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.192117] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.192227] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.192235] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Apr 24 04:11:48 ubuntu kernel: [  222.192268] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

```
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.822778] ata1: EH complete
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846957] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x450100 action 0x6 frozen
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846964] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846969] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData PHYRdyChg CommWake Handshk }
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846976] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846985] ata1.00: cmd 35/00:00:00:00:00/00:04:00:00:00/e0 tag 31 dma 524288 out
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846985]          res 50/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846989] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  208.846996] ata1: hard resetting link
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.162445] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.174828] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.174838] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:21 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.174845] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.228657] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.228674] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.228679] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.257235] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.266501] ata1: EH complete
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307284] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x450100 action 0x6 frozen
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307292] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307297] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData PHYRdyChg CommWake Handshk }
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307302] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307311] ata1.00: cmd 35/00:00:00:00:00/00:04:00:00:00/e0 tag 2 dma 524288 out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307311]          res 50/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307315] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.307324] ata1: hard resetting link
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.622114] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.634228] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.634236] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.634240] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.686520] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.686528] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.686532] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.714725] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.724038] ata1: EH complete
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754765] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754773] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x450100 action 0x6 frozen
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754779] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754784] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData PHYRdyChg CommWake Handshk }
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754790] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754804] ata1.00: cmd 35/00:00:00:00:00/00:04:00:00:00/e0 tag 4 dma 524288 out
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754804]          res 50/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754809] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 24 18:56:22 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  209.754820] ata1: hard resetting link
Apr 24 18:56:24 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  211.967254] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 320)
Apr 24 18:56:24 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  211.977178] ata1: hard resetting link
Apr 24 18:56:26 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  214.187128] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 320)
Apr 24 18:56:26 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  214.188545] ata1: hard resetting link
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395665] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 320)
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395682] ata1.00: disabled
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395742] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395749] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395754] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, hard reset required
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#4 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395765] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395775] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395793] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395798] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 2, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395802] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 3, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395806] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 4, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395810] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 5, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395815] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 6, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395819] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 7, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395823] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 8, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.395827] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 9, lost async page write
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396026] ata1: EH complete
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396038] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396051] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396070] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396075] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 131072 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396185] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396200] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396207] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 536870912 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396242] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396250] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396257] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396261] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396267] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396275] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396282] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396288] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396291] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396297] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396305] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396314] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396318] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396324] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396332] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396340] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396347] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396353] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396362] sda: detected capacity change from 1000204886016 to 0
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396420] sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396435] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953523712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 14 prio class 0
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.396983] ata1.00: detaching (SCSI 0:0:0:0)
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.398145] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Apr 24 18:56:29 mayank-X510UNR kernel: [  216.398193] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107143/discussion-on-question-by-mayank-srivastava-input-output-error-in-read-dev-sd).

Answer (score 3):

**NCQ errors**

You're getting NCQ errors...

```
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979055] ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979060] ata1.00: cmd 61/00:08:00:64:70/04:00:74:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 524288 out
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979060]          res 40/00:08:00:64:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Apr 22 16:51:44 ubuntu kernel: [  175.979062] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

<strike>We'll have to temporarily try this...</strike>

- boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- at the GRUB menu screen, hit the "e" key to enter edit mode
- use the arrow keys to find "quiet splash"
- change it to "quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
- hit control+x, or F10, to continue booting
- try and complete the rest of my answer
- we'll make the ncq patch permanent after you install Ubuntu

Try this then...

- create an externally bootable USB Ubuntu installation
- edit /etc/default/grub (`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`)
- find "quiet splash"
- change it to "quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
- save the file and quit `gedit`
- `sudo update-grub`
- `reboot`
- then retry `gparted`, `fsck` and `bad blocking`
- if that'all works, install Ubuntu to the internal HDD
- if that works, boot to Ubuntu and apply this permanent ncq patch

**Note**: Since the HDD is empty, using `gparted`, lay down a fresh MBR/GPT partition table (this will wipe the disk), then create one large ext4 partition...

**fsck**

First we check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors

**bad blocking**

You have read errors, seek errors, and 234 bad sectors.

Then we bad block the disk...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do a
         read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block
         scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

**Update #1:**

After the ncq, fsck, and bad blocking, it looks like the HDD will need to be replaced.

Comment: What's the secret behind using the `-c`-option twice in `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX`?

Comment: @mook765 from the man page, outlined in my answer... "If this option is specified twice,  then the bad block scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.".